# reselect using useSelector react-redux hook - state is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reselect

I'm having an issue integrating `reselect` when using `react-redux`'s `useSelector` hook.

For some reason, the state in my selector is always undefined.
I reproduced it in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/official-redux-hooks-sample-7muyt).

(Take a look at the `Simple.js` component). The state is fine in the `useSelector` hook but is then undefined when inside the selector. I added console logs that demonstrate the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a result function:

```
const selector = createSelector(
  state => ({
    ...state.reducer
  }),
  state => state
);
```

According to the [API docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#createselectorinputselectors--inputselectors-resultfunc):

> `createSelector(...inputSelectors | [inputSelectors], resultFunc)`

[image: Edit Q-59552085-ReselectExample]